# Not able to export product csv in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, export

When i try to export csv from backend it get the message **"Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon"**. but i did not get any file later.
I tried this `4-5` time, same message appears.

what is the issue. Is the file getting saved somewhere into magento directory?

Comment: file export is added in CRON. it will be downloaded in `var` folder. please check var folder.

Comment: if CRON is not scheduled, run `php bin/magento cron:run`.

Comment: In which folder particularly ?

Comment: I think `var root`, with some job id file name

Comment: do we need to set cron for this? i get nothing when i run crontab -l

Comment: you can try `php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor` command. please see my answer.

Comment: Also read `queue:consumers:list` and `queue:consumers:start` command and their option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After export product, You will see some file at `var` folder like:

> importexport_5e57c6084a30b

After that you can run below command if CRON is not set

> php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor

Above command will create another file with your export data.

For more information, read thread at [GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23450)

Comment: This worked. Thanx

Comment: glad to know that..welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.3, Magento started using Asynchronous and deferred operations for executing heavy operations. You have to make sure that your crons are running and wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento queue:consumer:start exportProcessor
```

This command initiates the export processor consumer, which is responsible for handling product exports through the Magento message queue system.

Answer (score -1):

Disable the the Add Secret Key to URL option

- In the Magento Admin, navigate to Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security.
- Set the Add Secret Key to URLs option to No.
- Click Save Config.
- Clean cache under System > Tools > Cache Management or by running bin/magento cache:clean or in Magento Admin.

To get the export file, run the bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor command. After running this, the file should be displayed in the grid.