# Magento Export Message: “Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon”

Tags: magento2

I export the product - SKU only, but the csv file does not shown up...

Wanted to run this command, but don't know where to run it:
-**bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor**

Comment: Please check : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305586/not-able-to-export-product-csv-in-magento-2-3/305591#305591

Comment: to avoid running manual commands, setup CRON as per https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275556/how-to-enable-or-disable-crons-in-magento-2/275557#275557

Comment: You can run command in command line from project root directory

Comment: project root directory? but mine is not installed magento, i'm doing in a web magento

Comment: root directory means where all your magento files/folder are placed like app,bin,vendor etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can findout export csv file under `(magento root)/var/export` folder .

Or

run `php bin/magento cron:run --group default`

after successfull run refresh backend you can see their is a option to download the csv file.

Comment: where to find the folder or run the command? because mine is not installed magento, i'm doing in a web magento

Comment: See `https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/cron.html` . Save that setting on backend .I hope it helpful for you.